# Why should you pass a reference instead of a value when passing a derived class object to a function with a base class parameter in C++?

Tags: c++

If I remember correctly, in Java, we can pass a subclass to a function with a superclass. The code would look like this.

```
// Assume the classes were already defined, and Apple
// and Pineapple are derived from Fruit.
Fruit apple = new Apple();
Fruit pineapple = new Pineapple();

public void iHaveAPenIHaveAn(Fruit fruit) { ... } // :)
...
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    iHaveAPenIHaveAn(apple); // Uh! Apple-pen.
    iHaveAPenIHaveAn(pineapple); // Uh! Pineapple-pen.
}
```

However, in C++, I noticed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389580/passing-a-derived-class-reference-to-a-function-through-a-base-class-pointer) that you need to use a reference variable of the base class (Is that the proper term?) instead of a regular variable of the base class.

Assuming you have two classes: a base class `A`, and an `A`-derived class `B`.

```
class A { ... };
class B : A { ... };
```

If we have a `neverGonna()` function that takes in a class `A` argument, then why should the function look like this:

```
void neverGonna(A& a) { ... }
...
B giveYouUp;
neverGonna(giveYouUp);
```

instead of this?

```
void neverGonna(A a) { ... }
...
B letYouDown;
neverGonna(letYouDown);
```

What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: See [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: simply to avoid data slicing

Comment: You're not passing the object itself in Java either.

Comment: @molbdnilo In Java, you usually pass by reference but in C++, you are more explicit, right?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais in Java you *always* pass objects by reference

Comment: @Caleth I see. So, pass by value in Java is impossible or not?

Comment: you pass non-objects (int, bool, etc) by value, and objects by "value of object reference"

Comment: @Caleth I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais The word "reference" means subtly different things in Java and C++ (and in "pass by reference"). In Java, a "reference" is a kind of value that you can store in a variable, and these are the values passed to functions. When you "pass by reference", you pass a *variable* by reference and can assign a new value to it. Java does not support pass by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(B)` are not the same.  If a function  (in C++ or the like) takes a parameter by value, it must know how large the value for that parameter will be in order to interpret the values in memory correctly.  As a rough (but technically sketchy) example, suppose I have a function that takes an `A` and an `int`.  Maybe it expects the incoming values to be stored like

```
AAAAAAiiii
```

where the first 6 bytes are the `A` object, and the last 4 bytes are the integer value.  But I create a B, which looks something like `AAAAAABBBBB`... so now the function receives

```
AAAAAABBBBBiiii
```

and that's no good.  Passing either a pointer or a reference allows the function to know how many of the bytes its receiving represent that first parameter.

So why isn't this a thing in Java?  In java objects are always handled "by reference"; that is, when you say

```
Fruit apple = new Apple();
```

you're creating a variable `apple` which is a reference to a `Fruit`.  If a java method says

```
public void iHaveAPenIHaveA(Fruit fruit)
```

it's going to accept a *reference to* a fruit.

In other words, what your Java sample is doing actually is the same thing as the by-reference version of your C++ sample (the one with `void neverGonna(A& a)`).

Comment: So basically, passing by value would cut off the non-`A` data from `B` (which, as others have mentioned, is called object slicing) while passing by reference would allow the non-`A` data to pass "through." Am I right? Also, how does a function how know many bytes its receiving represents class `A` when you are passing by reference?

Comment: When you pass by reference, the function only needs to know how many bytes make up the reference in order to receive it properly.  Syntactic sugar aside, a reference is internally not much different from a pointer, so a reference-to-`A` is the same size as a reference-to-`B`.  The receiving function still only knows the layout of the `A` part of the `B` it received, but because of built-in polymorphism (i.e. the vtable for virtual functions) that's all it needs as long as the value wasn't sliced.

Comment: If you pass by reference, would object slicing still happen or not? From how I understand from the comment above, I think it will still happen since the function only knows about the layout of `A` and not the extra data in `B`.

Comment: No, as pointed out above, object slicing will not occur when passing by reference because the function can understand the incoming arguments without it.

Comment: So the function just needs to reserve memory for the reference?

Answer (score 5):

Objects in Java are referenced by pointers. (Java calls them "references".) If you write `Apple a;` in Java, the variable `a` is actually a pointer, pointing to an `Apple` object somewhere in memory. In C++ though, if you write `Apple a;` then the variable `a` contains the entire `Apple` object. To get pointers, you need to explicitly declare `a` to be a pointer variable, as in `Apple* a;`, or a reference, as in `Apple& a;`.

The same goes for function arguments. In Java, if you send an `Apple` to a method that expects a `Fruit` (assuming that `Apple` is a subclass of `Fruit`), what is actually sent is a pointer, and the object itself is stored somewhere else.

In C++, the object itself is copied, and sent to the function. However, if the function expects a `Fruit` object, and you send an `Apple` object with some extra member variables in it, the `Apple` won't fit in the space that the function has to receive the `Fruit`. The `Apple` object has to be converted to a `Fruit` object, and any apple-specific extra stuff is removed. This is called [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: Actually, `Apple a = new Apple();` would be a more correct equivalent for `Apple a;` in C++. `Apple a;` alone is an uninitialised pointer and will result in compilation errors.

Comment: A bit confused on this part, "In C++, the object itself is copied, and sent to the function." Wouldn't that be passing by value or am I missing something?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: Yes, that is pass by value.

Comment: And passing by reference would not copy the object to the function but rather a reference to that object would be sent to function. Is that right?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: Yes. (And to be complete: Java doesn't really have call by reference. Java always works with pointers to objects, and in a method call the pointer is sent by value.)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you pass the object by value, then a (temporary) copy of the object is pushed into the stack before the function is called.

Since the function prototype dictates that the input argument's type is the base class, that copy contains only the "base" part of the object.

In other words, the original object is "sliced" and your hope for polymorphism goes to waste...

Answer (score 2):

Because passing by value will cause object slicing. Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "Base foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "Derived foo()" << endl;
    }   
};

void print(Base b)
{
    b.foo(); // object will be sliced here
}

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived();
    print(*b); // passing by value will cause object slicing;
    return 0;
}
```

Since we passed by value `b` in `print()`, there would be object slicing and the non-`Base` data in `b` will be cut off. The output would look like:

```
Base foo()
```

instead of:

```
Derived foo()
```

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: yes. but the answer is only for `object slicing` so for brevity we focus only on the OP's topic

Comment: Yeah, I know but I just can't help notice the impending memory leak if the code is run.